# Non-finitely generated relatively hyperbolic groups

Tags: geometric-group-theory

As we know that free product $G_1\ast G_2$  is relatively hyperbolic with respect to $\{G_1,G_2\}$. So for non-finitely generated relatively hyperbolic groups we can take this example.
But i am looking for other than this example of relatively hyperbolic groups which is not finitely generated.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Take your favorite infinitely generated group $G$ and consider the pair $(G,G)$.

Comment: Thanks for your example, i already knew that. i am looking for non-finitely generated group hyperbolic relative to proper subgroups. sorry i have not mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 1):

If you ignore any finitely generated conditions then the group of all permutations on a countable set (any cardinal actually), $S_\mathbb{N}$, is a hyperbolic group. This means that it is relatively hyperbolic with respect to the identity subgroup. This is proved by George Bergman in *[Generating infinite symmetric groups](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0401304)* where it is shown that any generating set gives a bounded diameter Cayley graph.

Comment: but hyperbolic groups are finitely generated.

Comment: @Yogi "Ignoring finitely generated conditions...". Every Cayley graph for $S_\mathbb{N}$ is hyperbolic (and quasiiometric). In my experience relatively hyperbolic groups are said to be finitely generated(and their peripherals). Maybe say what definition of relatively hyperbolic you are using, it seems like this example could fit.

Comment: Also I am pretty sure you can still do "small cancellation theory" stuff, so you can take lots of quotients of free product examples.

Comment: One of the reasons to assume finitely generated for hyperbolic groups is to make it a geometric condition not depending on generating set, but this case doesn't depend on generating set

Answer (score 0):

Non-finitely generated groups which are relatively hyperbolic are studied in great details in a paper by V. Gerasimov and L. Potyagailo, available here : https://arxiv.org/abs/1008.3470